# Show Blazor App when indexedDB is already set

Tags: c#, blazor, indexeddb

If I am using an indexedDb as my local storage in my blazor app, how can I show the blazor app only when indexeddb is already initialized and have data? I only want to show the app when the indexeddb is already done

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options I found is on the mainlayout razor page, on the backend of the page you can already create the indexeddb, initialized it and populate the data. When it is already done have a boolean that will tell the main layout page to show the body of the page or communicate to the ui that the settings up of indexeddb is already done

Example:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    @if (!IsNotInitialized)
    {
        <span>Loading..</span>
    }

    else
    {
        <main>
            <div class="top-row px-4">
                <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
            </div>

            <article class="content px-4">
                @Body
            </article>
        </main>
    }
</div>
```